# Hiding Navigation bar in android from broadcast reciever

Tags: android

I have made my own lock screen using the below link:
[***https://stackoverflow.com/a/28603790/1083093***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28603790/1083093)
.

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

     // My Implementation ---------- >

   }

}
```

---

**What I am trying to achieve:**
I want to hide the top task bar and bottom navigation bar in android

---

**What i tried:**

1. I tried to use [***Immersive mode from this post***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135886/1083093) but since
   `getWindow()` is not accessable there & since it is not an activity, I am
   not able to do that.
2. I also tried casting from `Activity activity = (Activity) context;`
   but it dosen't work .

---

**How to achieve this ?**

Comment: You have context in onReceive method why don't you use it

Comment: Using the context its not possible to get the `getWindow()` method even though I cast it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785784/how-to-use-context-inside-the-broadcast-receiver try this

Comment: Is your application in foreground when the `onReceive` is called?

Comment: NO it is not .... A service is invoking this calss